# Add click event using jQuery to radio buttons with name property

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I have a code and it has lots of tr tags like the following and I want to add onclick event dynamically
to the radio buttons in them...

```
<tr class="main3" id="2aiv">
    <td>iv. Hb</td>
    <td>Yes<input type="radio" name="2aiv" value="1" /></td>
    <td>No<input type="radio" name="2aiv" value="0" /></td>
</tr>
```

In a function if some condition is true I use the following code to add a class to tr tag

```
$('#2aiv').addClass('notAns');
```

which results to the following (this is working fine)

```
<tr class="main3 notAns" id="2aiv"> .... </tr>
```

the problem is when I try to use the following is does nothing...

```
$('input[name^=2aiv]').click(removeCls('2aiv')); 

function removeCls(id)
{
   $('#'+id).removeClass('notAns');
}
```

Actually I want to add an onclick event on radio button i.e. when they are clicked if notAns class is present in parent tr tag is should be removed

Comment: I'm sorry I crossed check before posting but I guess i missed the starting.. I meant " I have a code and it have lots ot tr tags..."

Comment: Where specifically does it fail?  When you debug this, does the jQuery selector find the element(s) you're targeting?

Comment: @david after running this code I use firebug to check the dynamic code but I dont see the onclick event added to the radio button. I cannot figure out the problem. Can you please guide me how to check whether or not jQuery selector finds the element..

Comment: You'll never see an onclick attribute added to anything, it's adds an event listener ?

Comment: @Parminder use `alert()` or `console.log()` to debug javascript.

Comment: @adeneo So you mean to say that I should check the DOM panel in firebug to see if it added the code??

Comment: @Parminder: Place a debugging breakpoint on the line which uses the jQuery selector.  When the debugger stops on that line, invoke the selector manually on the JavaScript console.  See what it returns.  Continue debugging from there...

Answer (score 1):

You are missing syntax to bind event, need to add `function()` and then call `removeCls` inside it.

Change this

```
$('input[name^=2aiv]').click(removeCls('2aiv'));
```

to

```
$('input[name^=2aiv]').click(function(){removeCls('2aiv');});
```

Comment: I tried this, but nothing seems to happen. It is not adding anything to the radio button...

Comment: are there duplicate ids in your html. Please check for console errors.

Comment: no duplicate id.  but I do have duplicate names as shown in code.. and console shows no error..

Comment: duplicate name does not matter. but it is working at my side see this http://jsfiddle.net/MS3EU/11/  are you creating these elements dynamically?

Comment: @Parminder, make sure that addClass and click event code should be inside document.ready and keep removeCls function outside it.

Comment: yes I saw the fiddle its working  but I am not able to figure out what is the problem at my end. Any suggestion??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57272/discussion-between-parminder-and-bhushan-kawadkar).

Answer (score 0):

your

```
$('#2aiv').addClass('notAns');
```

and

```
function removeCls(id)...
```

actually work

took your code, did a view changes and added it to a jsfiddle

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/DbMz4/)**

actually it adds a class and it removes it after clicking a radio

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `.change()` instead of using `.click()`

```
    $('input[name^=2aiv]').change(function() {
//Your function

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
<table>
    <tr class="main3 notAns" id="2aiv">
        <td>iv. Hb</td>
        <td>Yes<input type="radio" name="2aiv" value="1" /></td>
        <td>No<input type="radio" name="2aiv" value="0" /></td>
    </tr>
    </table>

    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('input[name^=2aiv]').click(function(){

            removeCls('2aiv');

        });

    });
    function removeCls(id)
    {
       $('#'+id).removeClass('notAns');
    }
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GqLMu/)**